# How to create virtual file system that file path can be accessed same as disk

Tags: c++, windows, filesystems

I need to create FileSystem type of thing in memory or on disk, which can be accessed same as file on disk, which path is can be used in function like fopen(),etc.

Details:
I am using AddFontResourceEx function to load font in application. Since this function require file path so that file need to present on disk. But I've requirement, that the user cannot access/see the font file.

I tried AddFontMemResourceEx function, but the loaded font is not enumable so that user cannot see the font in the application. Also I tried with some library which create VFS, but they work like database, i.e you can create file/directory and access them. But cannot use their file path in AddFontResourceEx or any other function.

Is there exist some way by which I can create a Virtual FileSystem in memory or on disk which can be accessible through my application and I can write/read file on this virtual filesystem created and it's file path can be used by AddFontResourceEx function.

Comment: Start looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace

Comment: Why not use font in temp file?

Answer (score 2):

It can't really work. Yes, you can add a "virtual" file system. But either it's visible to user X or it isn't. Access Control on Windows works on a per-user base, not a per-program base. So, if user X can see the font in application A, he can also see it in application B - even if B is Explorer.EXE.

Answer (score 0):

*If you didn't get the right answer, maybe you didn't ask the right question*

Your post title mentions "virtual filesystem", but. later, you mention "accesing a font".

**"Virtual Filesystems" its an ambiguos term used in several ways.**

One common case, means adding devices or networks to an O.S.

In your case, seems like accesing from a an application.

There are several ways ( "libraries" ) to emulate or work with a filesystem.

Some of them work independent of the real filesystem. You work with them, save data in those "virtual" folders & files, and copy data from the real and the virtual one.

Some of them work, as a extension layer, between the real filesystem, and the programming filesystem.

Example: I worked with an application, that required temporally fast I.O. access. Found a library, that when you want to create a folder or save a file in the real filesystem, was done.

Additionally, I could add "virtual drives" that where stored in memory, but, accessed with file system operations. When the application finished, the "hard drives" and their data where erased from memory.

Its seems that your case is similar to my example.

What do you want a "virtual filesystem" library for ?

I have seen onb the web, several libraries, for C++, open source, freeware, and commercial.

It depends what do you want to do, to find out, which library its the better for your case.

Good Luck

Comment: As mentioned in problem, AddFontResourceEx require file path as one of its param. So I just want to protect the font file from user anyhow. Either by using some complex thing like VFS, or cryptographically. If you have any idea on this, PLEASE share. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

If the user is an administrator, you can't really prevent them from seeing the font file if they're determined enough.  They could, for example, reverse engineer your program to figure out how you're generating the file and repeat the process by hand to make their own copy.  Or (even if you could somehow tie the file permissions to your process) they could insert their own code into your process to retrieve the file, or to retrieve the font information directly from memory.

If it's good enough to make it difficult for them to see the font file, you could try this:

1. Create a directory in the temp folder, with write-only permission for the current user and no permissions for anyone else.
2. Create a sub-directory with a long, complex, cryptographically random name, and with full permission for the current user.  (The name should be different each time.)
3. Write the font file to the sub-directory and load it.
4. Delete the font file and remove both directories.

The entire process should take only a fraction of a second, which should make it somewhat difficult for the user to override the permissions and retrieve the file.  If they use a debugger to single-step through the program then I guess you're out of luck, but as I already pointed out, nothing's going to stop everyone.

Another option, presumably, would be to just use AddFontMemResourceEx and put up with the fact that the font isn't then enumerable.  You'd just need to change your code so that wherever it enumerates fonts it adds your font(s) to the list manually.

Comment: I tried as you have mentioned, but the problem is if the loaded font is active then application don't allow to delete the font. Thanks For your reply.